# WPF Popup close on long running process

Tags: wpf, multithreading, popup

I have a Popup, which has a button. On clicking the button, it will call a long running methos which runs in background worker. The popup is not closed until the process complete.

I tried IsOpen to false on button click. But still it closed after the process complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an `async` method for the long running process so that your UI will not freeze. Before calling the `async` method set your `IsOpen` to false, Notify it to the UI and then call your `async` method

Comment: If you provide me with the xaml code for the button click and the code for the event I can then give you a better solution. Just post the code snippet.

Comment: I am already using Background Worker to avoid UI freezing.

Comment: Dude, if someone that is trying to help you requests that you show them your code so that they *can* help you, you should show them your code. There are many ways to achieve what you want, but probably nobody is going to give you a full solution when they could just alter a line or two in your current solution to make it work the way you want. Please help us to help you. You say that you're using the `BackgroundWorker` to avoid UI freezing, but it sure sounds like it's freezing to me.